# Debugging scenarios - Profiling Vs Dumps - C#

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, profiling, dump

To debug issues like memory leak, high CPU usage, high thread count, etc, profiling and dumps are useful. But still not clear on what are the exact scenarios where profiling would be useful and dumps would be useful.

Lets say If I have to configure to take profiling and dumps based on a custom metric reaching a threshold,

1. How to decide whether to take profiling or dumps? Is dump a superset of profiling?

Comment: Traditionally dumps are used for post-mortem analysis of crashes, that usually occurred at client sites, whereas profiling is used to measure performance and/or resource consumption, typically in a development environment.

Comment: Production for example. You won't be able to profile in production, but you will be able to take a dump. Profiling can show the dynamic and dump only the state. Just different tools.